# Binary search Tree recursive deletion (python)

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function for my BST class that will allow me to delete a node from the tree but when I run it on a node with two children it reaches maximum recursion depth and I cannot figure out what is wrong and what I need to change. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def delete_node(self, node):
    self.number_children = self.num_children(node.value)
    if self.number_children == 0: 
        if node.parent !=None:
            if node.parent.left_child == node:
                node.parent.left_child = None
            else:
                node.parent.left_child = None
        else:
            self.root = None
    elif self.number_children == 1:
        if node.left_child != None:
            self.child = node.left_child
        else:
            self.child = node.right_child
        if node.parent != None:
            if node.parent.left_child == node:
                node.parent.left_child = self.child
            else:
                node.parent.right_child = self.child
        else:
            self.root = self.child

        self.child.parent = node.parent

    elif self.number_children == 2:
        self.replace = self.replacment(node)
        node.value = self.replace.value
        self.delete_node(self.replace)

#case for value not found
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: You are using a lot of `self` variables that should just be local variables.  `number_children` is not an attribute of the tree, it is an attribute of the node, right?  What does `self.num_children(node.value)` do?  If it is returning the number of children, shouldn't you pass it `node`?

Comment: from BST which node you are trying to delete ? like property should be there like if node.val=xyz then delete this node?

Comment: Consider that after `node.value = self.replace.value`, you now have two nodes in the tree with the same value, so what is `self.num_children(node.value)` going to return?

Comment: Thank you I figured it out thanks to your comment @Tim Roberts. I really appreciate it